# Left Horizontal scroll when <div> is creating at run time in left hand sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I am making one tree structure with help of jsplumb API . When parent I am dropping a item in a , then two more divs are creating at run time by jquery according to position of parent div.

```
   <div id="win" style="overflow: scroll">
        <div id="rootNode">Drag New item Here</div>
    </div>
```

after dragging a item two divs are creating

```
    //getting postion of parent node
        var left= parseInt((document.getElementById("node").style.left).replace("px",""));
        var top= parseInt((document.getElementById("node").style.top).replace("px",""));
    var idValue = //clicked node id which contains "node"
    Left child:     
    $("#win").append("<div id='"+idValue+"1' class='window droppable' style='left:"+(left-150)+"px; top:"+(top+80)+"px'>Drag New item Here</div>");

    Right Child:
    $("#win").append("<div id='"+idValue+"2' class='window droppable' style='left:"+(left+150)+"px; top:"+(top+80)+"px'>Drag New item Here</div>");
```

all divs are creating inside of `#win` div

problem: After dropped item two childrens are creating.
if right child is crossing width of `#win` div, then srcoll is appearing. But if left child is crossing width of `#win` div(on left side as it is creating left side of current node), then horizontal scroll is not working for left child div. left node is creating somewhere with css.left of - value. that's why it is not visible even by using scrollbar I cant find left child node as scrollbar start from 0 not from -value.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it appearing? If yes, is it not scrolling the content?

Comment: Yes, it is not scrolling left div that is hiding left side of win div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sovled my problem by shifting all elements to right if `left-150<0` like below

```
    var left= parseInt((document.getElementById(idValue).style.left).replace("px",""));
    //left is clicked element's left css value

    if((left-150)<0){
            var leftShift=0-(left-150);
            $('[id^='+"node" + ']').css("left","+="+leftShift);
            //showTree();
    }
```

added 150 in css property `left` of all existing and newly created node.